# mod_rewrite failing to redirect, instead getting 404s - Apache 2

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to set up mod_rewrite on a newish, fairly clean install of Apache 2, on Ubuntu 8.04. However, whenever I test the URL-to-be-redirected, I get a 404.

I ran a2enmod rewrite and a2enmod proxy; as far as I can tell, they were successful - my mods-enabled directory contains proxy.conf, proxy.load, and rewrite.load.

My vhosts file includes this:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/saveplay
<Directory /var/www/saveplay>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

and my .htaccess file is in the relevant directory. (It's currently owned by www-data; it didn't work when it was owned by root either.) It looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/koolaid$       https://www.kintera.org/site/c.leJNIPOvErH/b.5926197/k.4F51/Save_Play_Donation_Form/apps/ka/sd/donor.asp?source=koolaid  [R=301]
```

I am sure there is something desperately stupid and simple that I am missing, but my google-fu is failing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just redirecting everything at /koolaid to a new location couldn't you just use the following in your .htaccess?

```
Redirect 301 /koolaid https://www.kintera.org/site/c.leJNIPOvErH/b.5926197/k.4F51/Save_Play_Donation_Form/apps/ka/sd/donor.asp?source=koolaid
```